# Counting from database

Tags: prolog

My database consists out of predicates like these:

road(1,2,geel).
road(2,3,blauw).
road(1,3,geel).

where the first 2 numbers are points. I have to check wether every point has a even number of roads. I managed to do it with the following code, but somehow I think there's a better way of doing this.

```
% Count(Element, List, Occurences) => Counts the amount of occurences of Element in the    given List
count(_, [], 0).
count(X, [X | T], N) :-
  !, count(X, T, N1),
  N is N1 + 1.
count(X, [_ | T], N) :-
  count(X, T, N).

checkRoad :-
    findall(Point,(weg(Point,_,_) ; weg(_,Point,_)),List),
    list_to_set(List,K),
    foreach( (member(P,K), count(P, List,N)), N mod 2 =:= 0 ).
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach would have better performance:

```
checkRoad:-
  findall(Point,(road(Point,_,_) ; road(_,Point,_)),List), % renamed wge/3 with road/3
  msort(List, SList),
  checkEven(none, SList).

checkEven(_, []).
checkEven(Item, [Item|SList]):-
  !,
  checkOdd(Item, SList).
checkEven(_, [Item|SList]):-
  checkOdd(Item, SList).

checkOdd(Item, [Item|SList]):-
  checkEven(Item, SList).
```

If you first sort all the points then you can just traverse this sorted list once to test whether every point appears in an even number of roads.